# LLDB Python API GetArrayType() Equivalent in Version 3.9

Tags: python, lldb, clion

**TLDR:**

In LLDB 4.0+ `x.GetArrayType(n)` can be called to generate the a fixed size array type for some given element type `x`. How can this be achieved in LLDB 3.9? Reason is that I am using CLion and the current version 2017.2 only supports LLDB 3.9.

**Details**

I am writing a synthetic provider for a class that looks like

```
struct X
{
    int n_a;
    int n_b;
    ...
    double * a;
    double * b;
    ...
};
```

I.e. it has a bunch of pointers and corresponding sizes. I know this could/should be refactored - but this is not my question.

I want to write a synthetic provider in for LLDB to visualize the arrays properly. My idea was to do sth. along the lines of

```
def get_child_at_index(self, index):
    ...
    if is_pointer(index):
        size = get_array_size(index)
        name = get_name(index)
        child = self.value.GetChildMemberWithName(name)
        data = child.GetPointeeData(0, size)
        array_type = ???
        return self.value.CreateValueFromData(name, data, array_type)
```

So given the `index`, I can determine if it's a pointer, get the size and name. My problem is that I need to then construct an `SBType` instance that corresponds to `double [size]`. This is exactly what `GetArrayType(size)` seems to do but it is unavailable to me.

Alternatively, is there a better way to get `X` formatted in LLDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see an easy way to do this without GetArrayType.  You might try using an expression, but C is really picky about casting anything to fixed size array types, so I couldn't manage to cons up a good expression that will return you what you want.

The best I can think up is to flatten the whole thing.  I.e. num_children would return n_a + n_b elements.  Then child_at_index for 0 returns a[0], 1 return a[1], ... up to n_b returns b[0] etc.  You can name the children "a[0]" etc. so what you see will at least be clear.  But it won't have the nice nested structure and you won't be able to do:

```
(lldb) frame var myX.a
```

etc.

This does work pretty nicely with GetArrayType :-(